# Excel VB - Foreach loop inside Foreach loop (loop through Sheets, delete empty rows)

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

I am quite new to VB and have a probably simple problem - I need to go through all the sheets in a workbook and delete all the charts (scattered around), select last row which has data, move backwards and delete empty rows. I tried something I assembled from StackOverflow and even from MS site but nothing seems to work.

```
Sub DeleteChartsRowsAllSheets()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, chtObj As ChartObject, i As Long

    For Each Ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

            For Each chtObj In Ws.ChartObjects
            chtObj.Delete

            Next
        'We turn off calculation and screenupdating to speed up the macro.
        With Application

        'Turn off screen updating and calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False

            For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
                    Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            Next i

        'Turn screen updating and calculation back on
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True

        End With

    Next Ws
```

End Sub

Any tips? :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects` with `ws.ChartObjects` in the nested loop.

You're currently only removing charts on the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Does this need the "looping through Sheets" part or can I omit it ("Next Ws" part)?